# How do you hide the "[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart" message?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

I don't want to see that message whenever I save a file in my project. I already have

```
{
    "events": {
        "start": "node -e 'console.clear()'"
    }
}
```

in my nodemon.json to indicate my project has restarted.

Comment: Just curious, but why?

Comment: I'm making a screencast and the message is kind of distracting from the console.logs in the file I'm editing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can tell `nodemon` to be quiet, by passing the `-q` argument. According to `nodemon --help options`, this will:

> minimise nodemon messages to start/stop only

Usage: `nodemon -q`